# how to assign properties/explorer view to tree in Javafx?

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have a fall tree with output shown in picture below.In BorderPane "Center" a SplitPane is used to split the view. I want to assign the properties/explorer view to the tree branches & leafs, so that each branch and leaf should have its own properties/explorer view.

My question is this how can i assign this particular split's right side view shown in picture to branch "module" only, and what would be changes if user want this view to be assigned to any leaf. if user click on other branches or leaf this view/properties should not appear. if you need i can provide my sample code,its simple editable tree-view.

i tried but failed. Please

thank you
[image]

Comment: This is Old post and it is solved. so Please Don't provide Answer. Thank you